# SQL Table not found [Marklogic]

Tags: marklogic

I have a collection and I inserted a template so that I can make SQL queries. After making a simple query I needed to change the scalar-type in one column in the template. After updating the template I can no longer make SQL queries, I get an error saying the "Table not found". The template is in the Schema on Marklogic. I deleted the view and reinserted but still get the same error message. Any one know why this might be?

Comment: Can you share the relevant portion of the template? And maybe some sample of a document?